# npm react-native unmet peer dependency

Tags: react-native, npm

I've been trying to display a svg image on a react-native project, using react-native-svg-uri

Im using react:

> "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"

Whenever i try to npm install --save react-native-svg-uri in my project, i get console warning

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@>=15.4.0

I already tried to npm install --save react@>=15.4.0, but then, i get an error saying that react@>=15.4.0 is also an unmet dependency.

It seems that i have to upgrade my react to >=15.4.0... How do i upgrade it?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating npm.

If you are on linux, try updating **npm** using **npm** itself (globally):

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```